# Why can I not connect to SQL on my computer?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I am using SQL Server 2008 express edition. I have connected before. Now I get this error message:

> ### TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to GEF65439\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a
>   connection to SQL Server. The server
>   was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is
>   correct and that SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft
>   SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ BUTTONS:
>
> ### OK

Comment: Make sure that the SQL Server service is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Administrative Tools\Services and restart your process **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)**.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer, but where do I find that, in SQL Server Management studio or in Configuration Manager?

Comment: Ok, I found it in the coniguration manager. It showed the service had stopped. I started it and now it is running. Thanks very much.

Comment: @GeoffreyBernardo: If Alex answer solved your problem, you should mark this answer as the right answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Sql Server service is started in Administrative Tools -> Services.

What happens when you telnet to the Sql Server port, by default 1433?

```
telnet localhost 1433
```